# Azure webapp diagnostic log level

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I have created a small flask app in a docker container, and setup logging to log analytics.
Logging is done with the preview function Diagnostic settings with everything selected.

The logs gets saved as expected, but the colunm "loglevel" is incorrect, and inconsistent.

The applicaiton outputs this at start:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
2020-05-26 14:07:40,203 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Log analytics seem to parse this wrong:
[image]

Here, the warning is marked as informational, and the info is marked as error.

How does log analytics parse the log level?
And can this be changed, or is there a format the logs is supposed to be in?